# In VB 6 debug mode, problem with dll

Tags: dll, vb6, debugging

my vb6 app is not finding a dll that is residing in the same directory as the project.  What do I do to have the vb6 code see the dll?  When compiled to an exe, the code sees the dll if it is in the same dir as the exe.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you're in the IDE, the current directory will probably not be the project folder, but your VS6 / VB6 folder.

Try this as your program starts up:

```
ChDrive App.Path
ChDir App.Path
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could add the dll into the references of the project that needs to see it, and that should do the trick.
Hope that helps.